# Recurrence relations in computer science mathematics T(n) = 6T(n/6) + 2n + 3 for n a power of 6 T(1) = 1?

Tags: math, recurrence

Recurrence relations can be directly derived from a recursive algorithm, but
they are in a form that does not allow us to quickly determine how efficient
the algorithm is.

Please how can I solve this

T(n) = 6T(n/6) + 2n + 3 for n a power of 6 T(1) = 1 solution ?

Comment: replace n by 6^k and get T(k) from T(k-1) and finally from T(1)

Comment: Have a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57068/solve-recurrence-relation and the use of "Master Theorem" (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Comment: Do you need to find an exact solution, or just the asymptotic behavior (big O)? The latter is easy to do using the Master theorem.

Comment: I need to find an exact solution to the problem theoritically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This recurrence could be solved with [`rsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.recurr.rsolve) from [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest), Python's symbolic math library.

```
from sympy import Function, rsolve
from sympy.abc import k, n

f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')

# T(n) = 6T(n/6) + 2n + 3 for n a power of 6     T(1) = 1
T = f(n) - 6*f(n/6) - 2*n - 3
Tk = T.subs({n: 6**k, f(n): g(k), f(n/6):g(k-1)})

s = rsolve(Tk, g(k), {g(0): 1})
print ("solution for k:", s.cancel())

for k in range(0,11):
    print(f"k={k}, n={6**k}, T(n)={2*6**k*k + (8*6**k - 3)//5}")
```

This gives:

- `Tk(k) = 2*6**k*k + 8*6**k/5 - 3/5` or T<sub>k</sub>(k) = ((10k+8)6<sup>k</sup> - 3)/5
- `T(n) = 2*n*log(n)/log(6) + 8*n/5 - 3/5` or T(n) = ((n(10log<sub>6</sub>(n)+8) - 3)/5

First 11 values:

```
k=0, n=1, T(n)=1
k=1, n=6, T(n)=21
k=2, n=36, T(n)=201
k=3, n=216, T(n)=1641
k=4, n=1296, T(n)=12441
k=5, n=7776, T(n)=90201
k=6, n=46656, T(n)=634521
k=7, n=279936, T(n)=4367001
k=8, n=1679616, T(n)=29561241
k=9, n=10077696, T(n)=197522841
k=10, n=60466176, T(n)=1306069401
```

We can check the formulas via the recursive formulation:

```
def recursive_t(n):
    if n == 1:
        res =  1
    else:
        t_ndiv6 = recursive_t(n//6)
        res = 6 * t_ndiv6 + 2 * n + 3
    print(f"T({n})={res}")
    return res

recursive_t(6**10)
```

This prints out the same values for the same `n`.

Comment: Nit: It's a bit confusing that T(k) and T(n) mean different things. Ordinarily, you would require that T(k) = T(n) whenever k = n.

Comment: I now introduced Tk to help clarify the difference.

Comment: I don't think this works. `n` is supposed to be a power of 6, but you're evaluating for 6th powers instead, which isn't the same thing. The formula you give for `T(n)` doesn't work, either: from the documentation, it looks as though `rsolve` only works for specific forms of recurrence, not including this one.

Comment: The right solution appears to be `T(6**k) = (2*k+1)*6**k + 3*(6**k-1)//5`.

Comment: Apologies: on re-reading, `rsolve` *does* work for this, but to get the right solution you want to use `{g(0): 1}` as your initial condition instead of `{g(1): 1}`.

Comment: Thank you for checking this. I think my mistake was first using `n == 6**k` and then switching to `k**6`. I am correcting the program and the output.

Comment: The most condence form for the formula seems to be `T(6**k)=((10*k + 8)*6**k - 3)//5`, but it is hard to convince SymPy to write it in that form.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback ... i really appreciate.

Comment: In case you're wondering where i got the question from check analysis of Algorithms: An Active Learning Approach By Jeffrey J. McConnell .@johanc